# referencing an ID field of a form in Views.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to send the url of a model entry to via e-mail when my form is submitted

However when I reference my form.id like so

```
 + `'(http://localhost:8000/zipherJobCards/viewJobCard/'+form.cleaned_data['id']+')',`
```

I get the following error

```
KeyError: 'id'
```

Is there any right way to reference the id of an entry like this ?

Please see the full `send_mail` function here

```
def jobCard(request ):
    form = jobCardForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = jobCardForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            send_mail(
                'ZTS JOB CARD' + form.cleaned_data['jobNumber'],
                'A new job card has been loaded for ' + form.cleaned_data['customerName'] + ' with a Total Cost of ' + form.cleaned_data['totalCostOfJob'] + '(http://localhost:8000/zipherJobCards/viewJobCard/'+form.cleaned_data['id']+')',
                'it.zipher@gmail.com',
                ['it@zipher.co.za'],
                fail_silently=False,
            )

            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    content = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'main/jobCard.html', content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` (or `pk`) is not part of the form, it is the primary key that is set when the object is saved. You need to do `obj = form.save()`, then you can reference the saved object, like `obj.id`.